# How to delete repeated elements from array keeping the order unchanged in python?

Tags: python, arrays, sequence

I have sequence of integer elements in array "a" ,given below

```
a=[2,1,5,4,8,4,2,1,2,4,8,6,1,5,4,87,62,3]
```

I need the output like

```
output=[2,1,5,4,8,6,87,62,3]
```

I tried the built-in functions like `set` or `unique` but it arrange the
resulting sequence in ascending order, I want to keep the order unchanged.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sorted with key=list.index

```
>>> a=[2,1,5,4,8,4,2,1,2,4,8,6,1,5,4,87,62,3]
>>> new_a = sorted(set(a), key=a.index)
>>> new_a
[2, 1, 5, 4, 8, 6, 87, 62, 3]
```

Comment: thanks alot for quick response sir

Comment: i am using "numpy" so it gives error
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
what is this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[2,1,5,4,8,4,2,1,2,4,8,6,1,5,4,87,62,3]  
b = []
```

You can use

```
[b.append(x) for x in a if x not in b]
```

or easier to read

```
for x in a:
    if x not in b:
        b.append(x)


>>> [2, 1, 5, 4, 8, 6, 87, 62, 3]`
```

Comment: thanks alot for quick response sir

Comment: Sir can you please up vote my question, because i am banned from further queries.. thanks..@Tushortz